Map odom base link transformation
Hello i am trying to use a RTK GPS device which has in built camera and an IMU sensor. The output is precised odometry data in llh, ecef, enu format after an internal sensor fusion. Is it possible to use the enu output to be broadcasted as map to odom transformation and the difference between ecef and datum to broadcast the odom to base_link transformation.
Is it possible to build such an autonomous vehicle. I am using ROS2 Humble and Nav2 and no amcl because this gps device gives pinpointed location and once initialised the output of gps after internal fusion is always accurate.
Am i missing something or making a conceptual error?
